# Https with self-signed certificate in Android over Restlet

Tags: android, ssl, restlet, self-signed

I'm trying to implement simple Androd client with RestLet for my thesis.Evrything works well over HTTP but  I have to get it to work over HTTPS with self-signed certificate and this is were I have problems. 
I was unable to find any helpful articles or anything similar about how to implement this on Android with RestLet. I know how to do this with code from [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html)   but I need to do this with Restlet classes.

I managed to implement some code which will execute GET method ( though very slow, it takes about 20-30 seconds to get data from server) but i have problems with PUT method. 
I used the following code to implement HTTPS client

```
private static ClientResource makeInstance(String url, Context con) {
    Reference reference = new Reference(url);
    Log.d("URL", url);
    String keyStoreFileAbsolutePath = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(con).getString(
                    Constants.PREF_KEY_KEYSTORE_FILE_PATH, "");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",keyStoreFileAbsolutePath);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "ks090278d");
    System.setProperty("ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm",
            javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

    org.restlet.Context context = new org.restlet.Context();

    context.getAttributes().put("hostnameVerifier", new HostnameVerifier() {

        @Override
        public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
            return true;
        }

    });

    ClientResource resource = new ClientResource(context, reference);

    Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients().clear();
    Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients()
            .add(new HttpClientHelper(null));

    resource.release();

    return resource;
}
```

and I'm using it like this

```
ClientResource request = new ClientResource(url);
    request.setRetryAttempts(0);

    Series<Header> responseHeaders = (Series<Header>) request.getResponse()
            .getAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers");
    if (responseHeaders == null) {
        responseHeaders = new Series(Header.class);
        request.getRequestAttributes().put("org.restlet.http.headers",
                responseHeaders);
    }
    responseHeaders.add(new Header("Accept", "application/json;"));
    responseHeaders.add(new Header("Content-Type", "application/json;"));
    responseHeaders.add(new Header("Authorization",
            "Basic ZXN0dWRlbnQ6YW5kcm9pZA==;"));

    try {
        request.put(new JsonRepresentation(jsonString));        
        Response response = request.getResponse();
        if (response != null) {
            Log.d("Response", "HTTP Response: " + response.toString());
            ResponseHandler
                    .handleResponse(response);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

When I execute this request I'm getting "Internal server error - 500". I'm using basically the same code for GET method only insted of

```
request.put(new JsonRepresentation(jsonString));
```

I'm doing

```
request.get();
```

and it works (though very slow as I mentioned above).

I checked if this is due to some error with the server but I think is not because I managed to get appropriate response when I'm using code similar to the code from Android Developers and also when I'm trying to execute PUT to the same URL from RestClient in Chrome.

Can anyone give me any suggestions how to get this to work? I'm not sure if my aproach is good to begin with, may be that I'm gooing in the wrong direction from the start. 
Thnaks in advance.

Comment: Since you got a response from the server, it's not likely an SSL issue. You probably didn't send the correct request that the server would understand.

Comment: Yet another thing - I don't understand what you do with headers. If you want to setup request headers you can use something like this: Series<Header> headers = request.getRequestAttributes().get(
                                 "org.restlet.http.headers");
headers.set("name", "value");

Comment: To get more infromation about the error you might want to log response.getEntityAsText()

Comment: I changed the code which is setting the headers as you suggested but same happens. I already was loging response.getEntityAsText() but i didn;t mentioned that in my first post. It is returning some html page which basically says "There was error in application" and logo and some other info about my school. Nothing helpfull I'm afraid.

Comment: Instead of setting the HTTP headers manually, you should rely use the ClientResource Java method to do so. They will generate those standard HTTP headers for you. See this mapping table: http://restlet.com/learn/guide/2.3/core/http-headers-mapping

Comment: Otherwise, you should really configure finer grained debugging on your server-side to see what happens.

Comment: @Jerome
Problem is that I dont have access to server. Server is at my school and I only know how JSON object I'm sending to server should look like. I dont have a clue of how server is implemented and dont have premission to change it. I still have same problem even when I was seting headers as you suggested :(